# Selecting nth row in Inner Join on Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, inner-join

My gifts table has multiple rows that match the criteria in the inner join statement below.  I want to select a specific row (3rd, 5th or 32nd row as examples).  I have tried using Row_Number(), but it is a windowed function and needs to be within the select part (as far as I know), but that then throws errors, because the overall statement has to return only one value.

I have also tried using top and then selecting the bottom value of top (top 5 for example and then selecting the last value), but I was unable to get that to work.  With the statement below, how can I modify it to also select the nth row?

```
update output 
set output.gift_date01 = (select gifts.gift_date
                          where
                             gifts.gift_date >= '2015-1-1 00:00:00' 
                             and gifts.gift_date  <= '2015-12-31')
from output
inner join gifts on output.donor_id = gifts.donor_id;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I hope you realize that `output` is a keyword in SQL Server and that you should probably not name your table as such?

Comment: I don't see how you're trying to get the third one (or fifth or whatever) in your statement.

Comment: I can post how I tried to do it, but at the moment it does not try to get any by nth, because none would hold work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will get you close if it's not exactly what you're looking to do.

```
;WITH CTE_Gifts AS
(
    SELECT
        G.donor_id,
        G.gift_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY donor_id ORDER BY gift_date) AS row_num
    FROM
        dbo.Gifts G
    WHERE
        G.gift_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
)
UPDATE O
FROM
    [Output] O   -- Should be renamed to not a reserved keyword
INNER JOIN CTE_Gifts C ON
    C.donor_id = O.donor_id AND
    C.row_num = @some_row_number
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly.  Just a note to anyone who might use this: I had to ad "AS" after CTE_Gifts at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected my answer to include the `AS` keyword.